# Codename one actionlistener not working

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener, codenameone

I'm currently working on building my first app. :)
I've now coded several Forms, each in an own class. Now, I want to implement the navigation from one Form to another, this is pretty straight forward since there is always only one "next" Form for every Form currently.

So i tried to do this by adding a "nextForm" Form to every Class and I want nextForm.show() every time the "next" Button is pressed. I tried it this way:

```
login = new Button("Login");
    login.setUIID("nxtButtons");
    login.addActionListener((e) ->
            nextForm.show()
    );
```

So, when i actually click the button, nothing happens.

Is the way I try to code this a good way? This is the first time Im heading into GUI building and I don't have experience here yet. Maybe one of you guys could help me here :)

Thank you very much

Kind regards,

Max

Comment: I recommend you to use multiple panels over forms.

Comment: As @NikolasCharalambidis says, and as most all Swing experts will agree, don't throw a bunch of JFrames at the user as they won't like this design. Instead swap views. Please see: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636)

Comment: Hi, im talking here about the Codename One Stuff, I'm not using swing.

Comment: I nominated this to reopen as this is obviously not a duplicate (Swing guys please read the question first it literally starts with Codename One and is properly tagged)... I'm assuming `nextForm` is null and you should see the null pointer exception in the console somewhere. If not nextForm might be pointing at the current form which will do nothing. You can place a breakpoint on that line in the debugger and see that the breakpoint is reached then inspect the values of the variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `nextForm` is `null` and you should see the null pointer exception in the console somewhere.

If not `nextForm` might be pointing at the current form which will do nothing. You can place a break point on that line in the debugger and see that the break point is reached then inspect the values of the variables.

Comment: My fault, initialized the button twice which overwrote the function.. :)